# Streamlit loading column data takes too much time

Tags: python, pandas, streamlit

I use simple code snippet in streamlit which shows dataframe consisting of excel which i have. the problem is that it takes too much time to load data inside the filter column of streamlit area. in that filter area i make search on material name, but it takes even 30 seconds to load and show me the data which i am gonna select. How to solve it and make it fastest to select data?

The code is:

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd

@st.cache
def load_data(nrows):
    df=pd.read_excel('materials.xlsx',nrows=nrows)
    return df

df=load_data(100000)

species = st.multiselect('SELECT THE MATERIAL', df['Name'])
new_df = df[(df['Name'].isin(species))]
st.write(new_df)
```

[image: the excel file which has 20,000 rows by the way]

and to show how it is too slow selecting data, look at this: https://streamable.com/kjis2

Answer (score 3):

Ultimately, without knowing which *part* of your code is running slowly (and how much data you're actually loading), it's hard to give concrete advice. It looks like you're loading 100,000 rows from a spreadsheet. That's potentially a lot of data, especially if those rows are themselves large.

Some things to try:

- Add some performance instrumentation around chunks of code, to figure out what is running slowly. This can be as simple as just calling `time.time()` before and after a chunk of code, and outputting the difference between the two values:

```py
import contextlib
import time
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st


@contextlib.contextmanager
def profile(name):
    start_time = time.time()
    yield  # <-- your code will execute here
    total_time = time.time() - start_time
    print("%s: %.4f ms" % (name, total_time * 1000.0))

with profile("load_data"):
    df = pd.read_excel('materials.xlsx',nrows=100000)

with profile("create_multiselect"):
    species = st.multiselect('SELECT THE MATERIAL', df['Name'])

with profile("filter_on_name"):
    new_df = df[(df['Name'].isin(species))]
```

- Change the `@st.cache` annotation to `@st.cache(allow_output_mutation=True)`. This will let Streamlit avoid hashing the output of the function (which is a gigantic dataframe that may take a while to hash).
- Is it possible to load fewer rows at a time?
- Alternately, can you avoid loading all the data that's *within* each of those rows? (Do you need the "Synonyms" column, for example?) `pandas.read_excel` takes a `usecols` parameter that lets you limit which columns get parsed.
- If you do need all this data loaded in, could you store it in a way that allows for faster filtering? For example, it looks like pandas can interface with SQLite. Could you load your excel data into a SQLite database once, when the app first runs, and then perform queries against that db, rather than against the DataFrame?

Comment: @st.cache(allow_output_mutation=True) is not making any difference on the performance of the data load. Again loading the data upon selecting material name takes too much time to appear. As i said my excel has 2000 rows and 3 columns and even each column has various data inside.

Comment: It may well be that the dropdown control in the browser is not well suited to displaying 2000 items. You haven't provided any profiling data, so all we can do is make guesses about what is the root cause of the slowness, but a 2000-item dropdown is probably not especially usable. Can you display that data in a different control? (Maybe use a text input control to manage filtering the data before populating the dropdown?)